# Possible to add Where filter to DbSet's?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've been developing an application in ASP.NET MVC5 using EF6. However, now the requirements have changed. This means my application now has to be multitenant. To do this I've added an extra id field to all my tenant specific rows.

However now I have to make sure my app filters on this id. The simplest solution would be adding a where statement to my Context, but I don't know if this is possible. Do I have to encapsulate all my DbSet's using repositories or something? Or is there an easier solution somewhere in EF itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally wrap it in a repository as you explicitly want the abstraction.

However something like this would also work just fine:

```
public class MyContext: DbContext{
    public IDbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities{get;set;}
    public IQueriable<MyEntity> MyNonDeletedEntities{
        get{
            return MyEntities.Where(e=>!e.IsDeleted);
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: The only reason I why I would not put it in repositories is so I don't have to refactor my complete codebase I have right now. With your solution I still have to do this since all the fetching of data would have to happen through MyNonDeletedEntities and all inserting through MyEntities.

Comment: @GlennVandamme if youre looking for a hack just swap the names around. ie `IQueriable<MyEntity> MyEntities {g{return AllMyEntities.Where(e=>!e.IsDeleted);}}` I havent seen any way to actualy do the filter inside the dbset

Comment: That was the kind of short-term hack I had in mind, giving me a bit more time to implement a permanent solution. However, this hack still wouldn't work for inserts unless I am missing something?

Comment: @GlennVandamme no it wont, this is a read only deal, you would need to  create a new wrapper type with an add method to support adds, that would be pretty messy. I would go for the re-factor.

Comment: So there's nothing in EF itself to do something like this, ah well, it was worth the shot. Thanks for confirming!

Comment: @GlennVandamme not that ive ever seen sorry :)

Comment: Just to add my 2 <yourcurrencyhereits2016>, I have a very thin "repository" layer which has a property called "baseAccess" whose "get" returns a queryable which is filtered by a where clause for whichever user instantiated the repo. This way, all calls for "get" or "getall" etc automatically have the filter applied.

Answer (score 0):

The question is old and although luke's answer solves the problem in a read-only scenario, I find it important to note that there is a solution that meets a read-only scenario, and also an insert, update, and delete scenario. With the advantage of requiring less code refactoring. Because it is not necessary to create new DbSets,

For this you should use the EntityFramework Interceptors, through them you can add features in the EF pipeline to meet your need. For example: To filter all queries in a table that contains the IdTenant field with the value of the tenant id.

The article below details how to implement interceptors for reading, inserting, and updating.
http://xabikos.com/2014/11/18/Create-a-multitenant-application-with-Entity-Framework-Code-First-Part-2/

This prevents developers from using a wrong DbSet and also addresses insert, update, and delete cases.

Interceptors are present in EF 6, but not in EF Core. For this scenario in EF Core you could use QueryFilters.